# Why does find sometimes find . and sometimes not?

Tags: bash, gnu

```
find -name "?"
find ~ -name "?"
```

Why does one of these commands find `.` and the other not? How can I make the second version, with an explicit path, find the `.` entry along with any other single-character file in the directory specified?

`find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11` in case it matters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the `starting point` for `find`, it uses `.` (the current directory). In fact, these two lines will produce identical output:

```
find -name "?"
find . -name "?"
```

To be able to specify a starting point *and* have `find` find the `.` directory, add `/.` to your starting point, i.e.:

```
find ~/. -name "?"
```

**Edit**: Now for the question of why, let's compare these two commands:

```
find ~/. -name "?"
find ~ -name "?"
```

There are two differences in their output. First, the command with `/.` produces results with an extra `/.` in each line, as would be expected. Second, and this was the OP's root question, is that the `/.` command finds the `~/.` pseudo-directory itself but the `~` command does not. This is because the `~/.` search explicitly asks for `.` to be searched. Unless it is listed on the `find` command line, `find` ignores the `.` and `..` pseudo-directories. (Can you imagine if it didn't?)

See `man find` for more information.

Comment: But why are they different? If ~ and . are the same directory then _why_ does one find  it and the other not?

Comment: I edited my answer to more directly answer the question of why.